# How can set in page title with the document name in Kentico?

Tags: kentico

I need set the page title dynamically because in my node actually exist 1000 documents, so I think that exist a way to do it automatly. 
I'm using Kentico 10

Answer (score 2):

Use a macro.  In the parent page of all your documents, you can use a field from the specific page type or use the document name.

For example if you have a page tree like this:

-Products
--Product 1
--Product 2

In the -Product pages metadata add

Page title: `{%DocumentName%}`
or
Page title: `{%PageTypeField%}`

Using the macro will allow you to dynamically get those values vs. having to code each one manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your question, but if you want:

1. To set page title for your documents, to be shown in browser, you should follow [link](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/configuring-kentico/search-engine-optimization/editing-metadata-of-pages) in documentation.
2. To iterate over all nodes and update document name/ page title with some custom text, you should look into [Kentico API docs.](https://docs.kentico.com/api10/content-management/pages) You should look into section for Updating published pages (see code example bellow):

   `TreeProvider tree = new TreeProvider(MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser);
   var pages = tree.SelectNodes()
       .Path("/Articles/", PathTypeEnum.Children)
       .WhereLike("DocumentName", "Coffee%")
       .OnSite("DancingGoat")
       .Culture("en-us");
   foreach (TreeNode page in pages)
   {
       page.DocumentName = "Updated article name";
       page.SetValue("ArticleTitle", "Updated article title");
       page.Update();
   }`